# Setting up screen mirroring on non smart TV

Tags: android, hdmi, video-streaming

I have a non smart TV with no inbuilt screen mirroring capability , just a simple HDMI port and two android devices HTC one mini and HTC desire 816 both of which do not support MHL. What would be the best way to connect it to my tv for screen mirroring